# VBA DOM getElementsBy can't get childnodes

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping, child-nodes

I'm trying to get the innertext of a label but i'm getting an error. Through the console i'm succesfully getting the inner text with this script :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("item alt")[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerText
```

Element i'm trying to get :

```
<tr class="item alt" data-id="1376936"><td class="toolbar left"><a href="#" class="show-incidents button-small ui-state-transparent-default rc" title="Details"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span></a></td><td class="time">14:00</td><td class="status"><span class="status-1 rc">FT</span>
```

My VBA script :

```
Sub WebScraping()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Set ie = New InternetExplorer


    ie.Visible = True

    ie.navigate "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/74/Tournaments/22/Seasons/7814/Stages/17593/Fixtures/France-Ligue-1-2019-2020"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to Whoscored ..."
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set doc = ie.document


    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to Whoscored ..."
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set a = doc.getElementsByClassName("item alt")(0).ChildNodes(2).ChildNodes(0).innerText
    MsgBox (a)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try this `doc.querySelector("#tournament-fixture td.status > span").innerText`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Set a = doc.getElementsByClassName("item alt")(0).ChildNodes(2).ChildNodes(0).innerText
> ```

Try to use the getElementsByClasssName method to find the child node, please modify above code as below:

```
Dim a As String   
a = doc.getElementsByClassName("item alt")(0).getElementsByClassName("status")(0).getElementsByClassName("status-1")(0).innerText

MsgBox (a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line in every module should be `Option Explicit`.

I'm not sure what you want at all. But to show the wanted element use this:

```
Sub WebScraping()
  Dim ie As InternetExplorer
  Dim doc As HTMLDocument
  Dim a As Object
  Set ie = New InternetExplorer

  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/74/Tournaments/22/Seasons/7814/Stages/17593/Fixtures/France-Ligue-1-2019-2020"
  Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to Whoscored ..."
    DoEvents
  Loop
  Application.StatusBar = False

  Set doc = ie.document

  Set a = doc.getElementsByClassName("item alt")(0).getElementsByClassName("status")(0)
  MsgBox a.innerText
End Sub
```